# Soft bodies (or cloth) with particle groups?

Tags: particles, soft-body

Hi I've got a simple scene of leaves blowing with a wind force and a particle system on a plane (that uses a group of leaves for the particles).

What I'd like to do is have the leaves bend and deform in the wind like soft bodies or semi-stiff cloth... is that possible? I tried to use soft bodies on the emitter and the group objects but didn't seem to work.

[image: Leaves]